# Getting error when trying to use JSON loads. Believe string to be in the correct format

Tags: json, python-3.x

When I try to use `json.loads` on this string in Python, I get the following error.

I don't understand why because I believe I am formatting the string correctly for JSON.

Code example below creates the following error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 132 (char 131)

import pymongo

import json

mongo_import_str = '{"Top_Level": {"NextLevelDown": {"First": "1","Second":"2","Third":"3"}}, "NextLevelDown2": {"First":"1","Second":"2","Third":"3"}}}'

mongo_import = json.loads(mongo_import_str) 
collection.insert_one(mongo_import)

Comment: Forgot to include the line of code that is causing the error:) This should have been just before the collection.insert_one(). mongo_import = json.loads(mongo_import_str)

Comment: Please edit your post so as to make it complete. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the JSON looks with some better formatting.

```
{
    "Top_Level":{
        "NextLevelDown":{
            "First": "1","Second":"2","Third":"3"
        }
    },
    "NextLevelDown2":{
        "First":"1","Second":"2","Third":"3"
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, there's a spare `}` in there. Remove it.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @RobertSparks If this answered your questions, remember you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark on the left!